# Is there a way to fuzzy match or provide a score as an assumption of what ID or Group the row value should be associated with?

Tags: r, tidyverse, approximation, fuzzy

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Date = c("2020-01- 
\n04", 
"2020-04-03", "2020-12-10", "2020-09-12", "2020-11-19", "2020-04- \n03", 
"2020-06-03", "2020-05-03", "2020-08-09", "2020-10-10"), Name = c("Jon", 
"Mike", "", "Rodney", "Jon", "Mike", "", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan"
), Phone = c("555-555-5555", "123-456-7890", "123-456-7890", 
"333-333-3333", "", "123-456-7890", "098-765-4321", "", "", "444-444- 
\n4444"
), Email = c("Jon@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com", 
"Rodney@gmail.com", "", "", "", "Ryan@gmail.com", "", "Ryan2@gmail.com"
), Address = c("123 Main Street", "456 Washingto Avenue", "", 
"16 Henderson St", "", "456 Washingto Avenue", "123 Lincoln Avenue", 
"123 Lincoln Avenue", "", "156 Jefferson Street"), Group = c("1", 
"2", "2", "3", "1", "2", "4", "4", "4", "5")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to get a dataset that looks like this (Note that the numbers in the score column are not exactly the ones I want. I just added numbers as place holders. I will allow the method to determine the proper score count. However 1 should refer to a perfect score.

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), Date = c("2020-01- 
04", "2020-04-03", "2020-12-10", "2020-09-12", "2020-11-19", "2020-04- 
03", "2020-06-03", "2020-05-03", "2020-08-09", "2020-10-10"), Name = 
c("Jon", "Mike", "", "Rodney", "Jon", "Mike", "", "Ryan", "Ryan", "Ryan"
), Phone = c("555-555-5555", "123-456-7890", "123-456-7890", 
"333-333-3333", "", "123-456-7890", "098-765-4321", "", "", "444-444- 
4444"), Email = c("Jon@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com", "Mike@gmail.com", 
"Rodney@gmail.com", "", "", "", "Ryan@gmail.com", "Ryan@gmail.com", 
"Ryan2@gmail.com"), Address = c("123 Main Street", "456 Washingto 
Avenue","", "16 Henderson St", "", "456 Washingto Avenue", "123 Lincoln 
Avenue", 
"123 Lincoln Avenue", "", "156 Jefferson Street"), Group = c("1", 
"2", "2", "3", "1", "2", "4", "4", "4", "5"), Score = c("1", 
"1", ".88", "1", ".96", ".96", "1", "1", ".25", "1")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The numbers in the column "score" are arbitrary. I'm ok with getting other numbers according to the rules of the fuzzy match process. The idea in my head is that based on the long dataset the script picks up that there are four groups. Those groups correspond to 1,2,3, and 4 which refer to Jon,Mike,Rodney, and Ryan. Note that the score for Ryan is .25 because it only includes his name rather than other information like phone or email. The score is relative within the group rather than relative to the whole dataset.

A completed set of

```
Col<-("Name","Phone","Email","Address")
```

should draw a one as in a perfect approximation without controversy. A set with 3 out of 4 should be higher than 2 out of 4 and so on. How to go about this process? Is this even possible?

Comment: Is your question related to how actually score each entry based on the quality/quantity of populated creterion or how to draw them once the score is calculated?

Comment: Yes. I selected arbitrary numbers that don't mean anything. I actually need something that would properly weighed the quality or quantity of the information provided.

Comment: Score is subjective, depending on the quantity of information you see in each information. For instance, you could imagine a weight on each column, and if the column is populated for this specific entry, you count it, otherwise not. Doing so for each column and lineary summing it (assuming perfect would be 100% i.e. 1) you would have a score. There are many other ways to imagine that: for the address for instance, you may want to check if it exist or not, ...

Comment: I first want it to recognize differences. Note that the name Ryan appears for two different groups. I want it to do as good as possible. Based on that, i want it to note that there are 5 groups including the two different Ryans. After that I don't really mind if it's not perfect, but i would like it be based on corresponding column count. If the phone number is different by one number then it is completely wrong. If there is a typo then it is completely wrong. Ryan@gmail.com and Ryan@gmail.com is a plus, "Ryan" and "Ryan" is a plus, but if enough info contradict then its not associated.

Comment: Based on the way you describe the process I believe it is proper approach.

Comment: I figured out a way to recognize the groups, so all i need at this point to assign score relatively within the group column